# OneHotEncoder input not working as an array

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding

I am currently following a tutorial for my project when it starts using the OneHotEncoder. When he inputs the following code:

type_one_hot = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False).fit_transform(
review_df.review_type.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1))

print(type_one_hot[0])

he gets an output of:

array([0., 1.])

whereas when I run the code I just get:
[0. 1.]

This matters for later on as when I later input using this style it complains that my input is not a vector. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty clear that what you have is a list and the tutorial is producing an array but can you check what `type` the values in your list are and it would help to know what these variables hold: `review_df.review_type`

Comment: numpy.array() does not change the list to an array it remains the same, and a list is usually separated by commas whereas mine is not? I am using the same data as the man in the tutorial there should be no difference.